# exclude one column from grouping in sql query

Tags: sql, group-by

I run an sql query to calculate mean and count after grouping combinations of `themes`, and `country`. This works fine.

```
create table georisk as (select themes, country , AVG(value) as mean, count(themes) as count from mytable group by themes, country order by themes, suppliers_country)
```

However, now I want to add an additional col to my table with the value `max(date_t)`without grouping by anything. A single value will be added for all the rows. If I do this:

```
create table georisk as (select themes, country , AVG(value) as mean, count(themes) as count, max(date_t) as last_included_date from mytable group by themes, country order by themes, suppliers_country)
```

the `max(date_t)` will also be according to the grouping. How can I just extract one max value within a single query?

Comment: You mean, every row has the same value, and that value is the max across the whole of the source table?

Comment: yup that's what I mean. Unlike the mean and count, it doesn't need to be grouped acc to anything. @MatBailie Just one max value for the whole table's date_t col

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Snowflake and Redshift are not conflicts.  Snowflake reads from Redshift (or Azure, or BigQuery...)

Comment: @MatBailie: according to [their homepage](https://www.snowflake.com/product/architecture/)  it's a complete database solution with it's own storage  (it does run on various cloud providers though)

Answer (score 2):

I ***think*** you want this...

```
select
  themes,
  country,
  AVG(value) as mean,
  count(themes) as count,
  max(date_t) as last_included_date,
  max(max(date_t)) over ()  as very_last_include_date
from
  mytable
group by
  themes,
  country
order by
  themes,
  country         -- Note, you had a typo here ; suppliers_country
```

The `GROUP BY` is evaluated before the `SELECT`, then the aggregates are evaluated, then the window function is evaluated.

```
MAX(
  MAX(date_t)  -- normal aggregate
)
OVER ()        -- window function across whole result set's values of `MAX(date_t)`
```

Normally a window function has a `PARTITION BY`, leaving it empty means 'no partition' and therefor 'whole result set'.